# Rotate Rigidbody in Unity starting from a value and proportionally to controller delta angle

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a disk and I want the disk to rotate in solidarity with the rotation change of the controller, the moment I press the trigger button on the controller. And then, for the disc to stop when I release the button. If I then press the button again, the disk must rotate again, but starting from its current position, and not starting from zero.

For example, suppose that at first the controller is at zero degrees.

1. I press the button and rotate the controller 20 degrees --> the disk must rotate 20 degrees.
2. Then subsequently my controller, say, is at 30 degrees. I press the button and rotate the controller up to 70 degrees (so with the button pressed I make 40 degrees -from 30° to 70°-) --> I want the disk to rotate another 40 degrees, that is, I have to make it rotate from 20 degrees (i.e. its current rotation), to 60 degrees (i.e. 20 degrees before + 40 degrees made now with the controller).

I'm going crazy! I can make it rotate. However, I attach the source code...

**A - in case A)** the disk keeps the same angle as the controller. That is, the first time the disk rotates from zero to 20° (correct). But the second time it rotates from 30° to 70° (copying the same degrees of the controller, wrong!)

**B - instead in case B)** the disk seems to rotate as I want, except that it perpetrates the rotation in loop, so the disk instead of stopping, rotates infinitely (with a speed proportional
to the angle of the controller).

I take the screenshot of the code, which I execute in FixedUpdate().
Instead, the variable `inputRotationStartRight` is equal to the angle of the controller at the time I press the button and I value it in Update();
The variable `_inputRotationRight.z` is the real-time angle of the controller.

Ps.  I need to call the method MoveRotation() because the disk has some teeth in the border and I need them to collide during the rotation.

Thank you all very much.

```
//Rigidbody disk ;

void FixedUpdate()
{
...

  if (_isTriggerPressedRight)
  {
    Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler((_inputRotationRight.z - inputRotationStartRight) * 180, 0, 0);

    //A) This way, infinite rotation
    disk.MoveRotation(disk.transform.rotation * deltaRotation);

    //B) This way, the disk has the identical angle of the controller
    disk.MoveRotation(disk.transform.rotation * deltaRotation);
  }
```

Here is how I set the variable `inputRotationStartRight` :

```
void Update()
{
    _deviceRight.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.deviceRotation, out _inputRotationRight);
    _deviceRight.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.triggerButton, out _isTriggerPressedRight);


    //If I click the button for the first time then I set the "initial angle" (on click) of the controller 
    if (_isTriggerPressedRight && !isTriggerAlmostPressedRight) {
        isTriggerAlmostPressedRight = true;
        inputRotationStartRight = _inputRotationRight.z;
    }
    
    //When I unclick the button, then I unset isTriggerAlmostPressedRight
    if (!_isTriggerPressedLeft) {
        isTriggerAlmostPressedLeft = false;
    }
    
    if (!_isTriggerPressedRight)
    {
        isTriggerAlmostPressedRight = false;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
//i'm assuming you original angle was in radians
//if this is not the case, remove Mathf.Rad2Deg
float deltaRotationAngle = (_inputRotationRight.z - inputRotationStartRight) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(deltaRotationAngle , 0, 0);
disk.transform.rotation *= deltaRotation;
```

Here the `disk.transform.rotation *= deltaRotation` is the equivalent of first rotating by the disk's original rotation, then by the `deltaRotation`.

If this gives you issues with precision and drift, then you could cache your angles at the start of each rotation, and add them back at the end.

Comment: Thank you Charly. However, I need MoveRotation because the disk has teeth and I need it to collide during its movement. I edit my question :)

Comment: Try [AddTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html).

Comment: You could edit my code and write instead `disk.MoveRotation(deltaRotation * disk.transform.rotation);` Sorry, I missed that you were using the physics system.

Comment: Hi @Charly, I tried your code with no success. The disk continue rotating (and the more I turn my controller, the faster the disk rotate). So, I edited my post adding a second statement in which I set the initial angle (ie when I press the button of my controller).

Comment: It seems that for every FixedUpdate, the disk restart moving (that if I rotate my controller of 30 degrees, every loop the disk rotates of 30 degress), and this is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did.

```
void Update()
{
    _deviceRight.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.deviceRotation, out _inputRotationRight); //
    _deviceRight.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.gripButton, out _isGripPressedRight);
    _deviceRight.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.triggerButton, out _isTriggerPressedRight);

    if (_isTriggerPressedRight && !isTriggerAlmostPressedRight) {
        print("BUTTON PRESSED!");
        isTriggerAlmostPressedRight = true;
        rotationStartDisk = disk.transform.rotation.x;
        inputRotationStartRight = _inputRotationRight.z;
    }
    if (!_isTriggerPressedRight) {
        isTriggerAlmostPressedRight = false;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (_isTriggerPressedRight) {
        Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler((_inputRotationRight.z - inputRotationStartRight + rotationStartDisk) * 180, 0, 0); 
        disk.MoveRotation(deltaRotation);
    }
}
```

I'm starting in these days with Unity, so I keep the question opened, waiting for further answers or suggestions.